# Attaching a VScrollbar to a control that already supports scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have an application written for a touchscreen. It mainly consists of a listview and a DataGridview. the default control scrollbars are too narrow for gloved hands, so i would like to increase the width of the scroll bars in those two controls.
I don't see any way to do it in the designer, so I started working with the VScrollBar control; however, this does not replace the default scrollbar for those controls, rendering it ineffective.
So, my question is twofold:
Can I override the width of the default scrollbar?
If not, can I somehow make the new VScrollbar the default for that control?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550618/changing-width-of-vertical-scroll-bar-in-datagridview

Comment: It is just the wrong way to do it, never write code to accomplish this.  The width of the scrollbar is a system setting.  Not the only one you want to change, basic stuff like the buttons in a message box and the height of the titlebar of a window should be bigger as well.  Now it automagically works for any program and any dialog, no code required at all.  Windows used to make it lot easier to change these settings, ask for advice at superuser.com.